# Register as inactive user and activate via mail

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I made a project with Symfony and with FOSUserBundle and PUGXMultiUserBundle, in which an user can self-registrate. 
I would like the user to automatically register as "inactive user", and to be activated by an Admin user directly from the web-site o from a mail, it's not important the way.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you first have to put a enable `flag` in your user table..
first put it as `disabled` or `0`..
and when user registers, throw him/her a `mail` containing his/her `userid` in the `activation link` and when the user will click on the activation link `get` his/her `userid` from `$_GET` and fire your `update query` and set the flag to `enabled` or `1`..
so simple as that..
let me know if you want any further guidance..

Comment: Yes, I need more help. I'm quite new of Symfony and programming, and I really don't know how to do it. 
One important thing: the activation must be done not by the user but by an Admin.

Comment: ohh okay.. than you just have to send the same mail to the admin.. not to the user... but I will not be able to help you for symphony as I also havent worked in that.. The thing I can do is just provide you the logic...

Comment: Is there documentation where I can study better the argument?

Comment: here is a link ....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844506/beginner-tutorials-for-symfony-2-x